# Erlang: Using gb_tree functions within beam executable, record operations?

Tags: tree, erlang, record

I have several questions regarding the use of the `gb_tree` structure such as basic input from the shell as well as using a tree within a beam executable without shell input.

The first question is how do I use the `Tree` returned by the `init()` function? 
Does `Tree` become global during the lifetime of the program? Do I need to pass the returned Tree from the shell into `add_entry()` for example?

The second question pertains to passing arguments into the `add_entry` function call such as `gbt:add_entry(x,"10")` but that gave me an exception error:

`** exception error: no function clause matching gbt:add_entry(x,"y") (gbt.erl, line 23)`

I also tried using `Tree = gb_trees:enter( value, Data, Tree)` inside `add_entry()` but then I received an error on compilation where `Tree` was unbound.

The final question I have is how would I store/retrieve/delete/update a record into the gb_tree called `mapping` (declared in the source)?

```
-module(gbt).
-export([init/0,lookup/2,retrieve/2, add_entry/2, delete/2]). % For test purposes only.
-record(mapping, {string="", parameter}).

init() ->
    Tree = gb_trees:empty().

lookup( value, Data) ->
    case 
        gb_trees:lookup( value, Data) of 
        none -> 
            false ; 
        _ -> io:format("ok~n") 
    end.

retrieve( value,Data) ->
    case gb_trees:lookup( value, Data) of none -> 
        false; 
        { value, Data} -> 
        io:format("~w~n", [Data]) 
    end.

add_entry( value, Data) ->
    Tree = gb_trees:enter( value, Data, Tree),
    io:format("~p ~p ~n", [value,Data]).    

delete( value,Data)->
    {value, Data} = gb_trees:lookup( value, Data), 
    Tree = gb_trees:delete( value, Data), 
    io:format("~w~n", [Data]).

%    reserve(Free) ->
%     case gb_trees:take_smallest(Free) of
%   {Min, Min, Free1} ->
%       {Min, Free1};
%   {Min, Max, Free1} when Max > Min ->
%       {Min, gb_trees:insert(Min+1, Max, Free1)}
%     end.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Data structures in Erlang are *persistent*. This means that there are no global reference and that you always update a given tree to a new one.

```
NewTree = gb_trees:empty(),
TreeOfSize1 = gb_trees:enter(hello, world, NewTree),
TreeOfSize2 = gb_tress:enter(foo, bar, TreeOfSize1).
```

Note that `TreeOfSize1` still exists and that it has no KV binding `foo -> bar`, because Erlang keeps a persistent version around. This is highly useful in many situations since keeping a reference to an older version automatically makes you able to "go back" to that version.

As for your bug, it is because you are writing `(value, Data)` and not `(Value, Data)`. Writing `value` is the `atom()` called `value` not a binding so when you pass `x` it does not match the function and you get a pattern-match function_clause error.

Comment: What about this line `Tree = gb_trees:enter( value, Data, Tree),`? Compiling the code tells me `gbt.erl:24: variable 'Tree' is unbound
`. It seems as if the code doesn't notice `Tree = gb_trees:empty().` where `Tree` is declared. I basically want the code to run without shell IO. Basically updating the `gb_tree` as needed by the code itself without any shell input.

Comment: @lost_with_coding, You actually store you tree nowhere. All variables are local for functions. So, init()-> Tree=gb_trees:empty(). means: when you call init(), you create empty tree, then make sure variable Tree is equal of that empty tree, then just forget variable Tree and return.

Comment: @OdobenusRosmarus Is there some way to make the Tree global within the instance of the running beam exe? Should I maybe put the Tree in a loop() and pass messages to it within the module, using other functions?